# Best way to filter to rows with partitioned SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table that consists of an order, items on that order, and then the quantity of the item ordered.

What I would like to do is create an additional column for 'Order quantity' which is the sum of item quantities grouped by order (see graphic of table below... order B has 30 total quantity split across three lines)

I can easily accomplish this using sum and partition:

```
SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) order_qty
```

However, what I need to is then filter to only those orders having quantity > 20. When I try to add that criteria to the WHERE or HAVING clauses, I get this error:

```
ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here
```

One solution appears to be to wrap the whole SQL block inside of another SELECT FROM statement, and then add a WHERE clause to filter by order_qty.  Overall that seems sloppy and non-intuitive... Is there a better solution to filter based on an aggregated value that is partitioned at a higher level?

[image]

Comment: what is wrong with subselect?

Comment: Maybe nothing. I'm just asking if there is a more efficient way. Plus subselect reduces code legibility imo.

Comment: can you post the full query?

Comment: This is just a simplified example as the actual query is much more complex...


select 
 order_id, 
 item_id, 
 quantity,
 SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) order_qty
FROM
 orders
HAVING SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) order_qty > 20

Answer (score 1):

Replace with

```
SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id order by 1) order_qty
```

Comment: This yields the same error. ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here

Comment: Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query. A window function cannot be a group function.

Comment: Are you use group by ?

Comment: @ibrahim yes, your  solution is good : `select o.*, 
        SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id order by 1) order_qty
   from orders o 
  order by order_id, item_id;` or subselect with grouping by order_id maybe prefered.